# How to formulate Langlands correspondence over a finite field?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

Langlands correspondence is a conjectural correspondence between automorphic forms over a reductive group and Galois representation. This is widely open subject in number theory and there are some known results for special cases (special groups over special fields). By the way, I think that representation theory of finite groups is much easier than general Lie groups because it is *finite* - we can actually count things and we don't need to concern about convergence issues. So I believe we can formulate Langlands correspondence over a finite field and even easily prove it, but I can't find any reference for this. (I strongly believe that it would be not that hard to prove, but I don't know what is a correct way to formulate it.) Am I right? Thanks in advance.

FYI, I read chapter 4.1 of Bump, which introduces the representation theory of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ which can be applied to $p$-adic general linear groups with some modification. But I don't know how to attach Galois representations to these representation of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to assume the finite case is automatically easier, and I definitely wouldn't expect it to be trivial.

Comment: In practice, you can't enumerate all of the elements of a finite group. $\mathrm{GL}_{2334566432}(\mathbb F_{7545911^{34556744}})$ might as well be infinite.

Comment: @MattSamuel What do you mean that that group is infinite?

Comment: It's not infinite, but it's very large. You can't enumerate all of its elements.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/finiteLanglandsAMS20HO.pdf
This might be of some help. I'm interested in how to formulate the Langlands program over finite field, too.

Comment: @Carlfu Thanks! I’ll read it.